# Cloud9 IDE with Vue.js vue component files?

Tags: c9.io

I'm trying to make my .vue components from Vue.js have their good syntactic coloration on Cloud9. Since the file is kind of oddly structured (`<template>` for template html, `<script>` for JavaScript and `<style>` for CSS, the file must be parsed in three different ways.

Is it possible and if so, how?

Comment: Any IDEs that support HTML should be able to parse .vue files. Just set the syntax as HTML.

Answer (score 2):

In the bottom, right-hand corner of any editor that has a Vue file open, you will see the word 'Text'.

Clicking on that word will bring up a list of options of how Cloud9 should interpret this file.

Choosing 'HTML' will likely give you the results you are looking for.